# Creating a console application in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to start learning C# language and for that I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and when I clicked on "New Project", the following appeared:

**I get a blank pop-up window with nothing to choose from different file types, NOTHING!**

I also completely removed all the components of Visual Studio and then again installed it all again, but nothing seem to work. I struck with what to do.

Also, you might be wondering why I installed Visual Studio 2010 and not 2013 or 2012 version. I did, but these both versions after taking long hours to install when opened up give an error that Visual Studio has stopped working and it automatically shuts down the window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: To see the screen shot: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/problem-with-creating-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-2010-ultimate

Comment: If you've got enough money to buy 2010, 2012 and 2013 ULTIMATE, consider buying a new PC first ;)

Comment: Raphaël Althaus, I have copies of all from my pals. So, my pocket is sealed :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all service packs for VS2010?

Have you tried manually installing the templates?

From [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

1. Open cmd.exe as an Administrator
2. Navigate to the location of devenv.exe
3. Execute **devenv /installvstemplates**
4. Profit?

Comment: Error: 'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you perhaps skip step 2?  (i. e. at the command prompt type `cd <Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE`  Note:  enter the correct path for your Visual Studio Installation where it says _<Visual Studio Installation Path>_

Comment: @SahilBabbar - Then how is VS even starting if the .exe is not there?  That makes no sense!

Answer (score 0):

You must download the templates. Since almost all visual studios comes with alot of languages like C#, C++, VB, F# and more. So you need to install it manually, maybe the installer will give you options to install which programming language and templates to install. And i recommend you to install Visual Studio 2019 community edition (at least windows 10 must be installed on your computer). You can choose the community, professional or the enterprise edition.